# Rewrite Rules: Adding an alias with static content without getting rewritten by previous rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache, vhosts

I have the rules (below) and we have added a new alias /msn which has some static content, like an html file `ayuda.html` which is the directory index file and some images.

Currently I can see the HTML file, but not the image. Also there are different errors depending if I go to `domain.com/msn` or `domain.com/msn/`. On the first case the image location is not being rewritten to `domain.com/msn/image-blah-blah.jpg`, but it does on the second case.

This is the Virtual Directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin administracion.linux@yellargentina.com
        DocumentRoot "/opt/tomcat-5.5.30/webapps/portalPA"
        ServerAlias *.amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com
        CustomLog /tmp/amarillas-access_log combined
        ErrorLog /tmp/amarillas-error_log
        RewriteLog /tmp/amarillas-rewrite_log
        RewriteLogLevel 9

        JkUnMount       /images/*.gif           w1
        JkUnMount       /images/*.png           w1
        JkUnMount       /images/*.jpg           w1
        JkUnMount       /js/*.js                w1
        JkUnMount       /styles/*.css           w1

        #JkMount        /jkmanager/*            jkstatus
        JkMount         /portalPA               w1
        JkMount         /portalPA/*             w1
        JkUnMount       /msn/*                  w1

        CookieName PaginasAmarillas
        CookieExpires "2 years"
        CookieDomain ".tm.yellargentina.com"
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
        Options +FollowSymlinks

        RewriteRule ^/(msn|msn/) /msn/ayuda.html [PT]
        RewriteRule ^/msn/ayuda.html$ /msn/ [R,L]
        RewriteRule ^/msn/(?!ayuda.html)(.*) /msn/$1 [R,L]

        RewriteRule ^/$ /portalPA/index.action   [PT]
        RewriteRule ^/portalPA/index.action / [R]
        RewriteRule ^/(?!portalPA/)(.*) /portalPA/$1 [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

Logs for when I try to access to `domain.com/msn/`

```
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:54:36 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc8338/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /msn/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:54:36 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc8338/initial] (3) applying pattern '.*' to uri '/msn/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:54:36 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc8338/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='GET' pattern='^(TRACE|TRACK)' => not-matched
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:54:36 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc8338/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/(msn|msn/)' to uri '/msn/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:54:36 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc8338/initial] (2) rewrite '/msn/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg' -> '/msn/ayuda.html'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:54:36 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc8338/initial] (2) forcing '/msn/ayuda.html' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
```

Logs for when I try to access to `domain.com/msn`

```
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc02f8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /msn
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc02f8/initial] (3) applying pattern '.*' to uri '/msn'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc02f8/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='GET' pattern='^(TRACE|TRACK)' => not-matched
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc02f8/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/(msn|msn/)' to uri '/msn'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc02f8/initial] (2) rewrite '/msn' -> '/msn/ayuda.html'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bc02f8/initial] (2) forcing '/msn/ayuda.html' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /yello-apps-mesenger.jpg
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (3) applying pattern '.*' to uri '/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='GET' pattern='^(TRACE|TRACK)' => not-matched
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/(msn|msn/)' to uri '/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/msn/ayuda.html$' to uri '/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/msn/(?!ayuda.html)(.*)' to uri '/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/$' to uri '/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/portalPA/index.action' to uri '/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (3) applying pattern '^/(?!portalPA/)(.*)' to uri '/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (2) rewrite '/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg' -> '/portalPA/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg'
10.248.19.52 - - [23/Aug/2011:16:55:33 --0300] [amarillas.tm.yellargentina.com/sid#2af084b03cd0][rid#2af084bb82b8/initial] (2) forcing '/portalPA/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg' to get passed through to next API URI-to-filename handler
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on rewrite logs provided I came to conclusion that `yello-apps-mesenger.jpg` is the problematic image in question. As I understand the aforementioned image is linked from that `/msn` page.

I think it is all about how you wrote your `<img>` tag (or where you are using that image). I guess it is declared relative to the current document like this: `<img src="yello-apps-mesenger.jpg" />`.

Well -- that is the problem:

- when you requesting `domain.com/msn/` that image will be requested like `domain.com/msn/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg`
- but when you requesting `domain.com/msn` (without trailing slash), the image will be requested like  `domain.com/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg` and `^/(msn|msn/)` simply not got applied to it.

TBH I do not know which one is doing wrong -- you are not clear on this (at least I cannot figure it out ATM).

I see 2 approaches to fix the issue:

**1.** Only accept `domain.com/msn/` and not `domain.com/msn` (or other way around) and build your rules with this in mind.

**2.** Fix image URLs -- make then relative to the website root, for example: `<img src="/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg" />` (notice the leading slash) .. or maybe `<img src="/msn/yello-apps-mesenger.jpg" />` (`/msn/` is part of image URL) -- you should know better what is good for you.